# Avoid the effects of a revert commit in another Git branch while merging

Tags: git, git-flow, git-revert

Working with git flow. We have a co-worker who is not familiar with Git that accidentally merged develop into master yesterday.

Develop has quite a few features that are launching with our next release, requiring a revert on the merge. This has created a commit which undoes all of the changes. When we merge master back into develop, the revert commit is removing code generated by our features.

What is the best way of going about being able to synchronize develop with master's hotfixes, while preserving the new features?

-- Edit --
Just to clarify, the revert was a *revert*. I.E. `git revert -m 1 <sha>`, as the commit had already been pushed to the remote repository.

Since posting this, I've come up with a possible fix, by branching master and reverting the revert, however I'm curious if there are other possibilities that may minimize collision.

Comment: Please add details on ***how*** the revert was done (especially the specific commands used). Was force resetting `master` to its previous state (instead of reverting) not an option?

Comment: Also, "accidentally merging branch X into branch Y" should not have been a problem if your coworker hadn't been able to push the merged results up to your canonical repo.  Please explain if your developers are all pushing to the same repo, or if you're all using your own private forks. Are you using pull requests via GitHub?

Comment: It's not Github, it's Gitlab utilizing the Git Flow framework, with standard branch recommendations.

Comment: The exact command was git revert -m 1 <sha> to force a rollback, as the commit had been pushed to the global repository.

Comment: What if you reset `master` to the state before merge and force push? It requires everyone to sync again but it preserves your history

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Comment: Possibly related: [Reverting a git merge commit, then reverting the revert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7969344/456814).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Option 1: Hard reset and force push

If it's possible to do a non-fast-forward forced-update to your `master` branch
in your upstream repository, then instead of reverting the merge of `develop`
into `master`, you could simply do a hard reset of `master`:

```bash
# On master branch, do a hard reset back to the commit before the merge
git reset --hard <commit of master before the merge>

# Force push to upstream ONLY IF IT'S OK WITH OTHER DEVELOPERS
git push <remote> master --force
```

A possible disadvantage to doing a hard-reset and force-push is that if other
developers have already based work off of the merge commit (i.e. have made
commits on top of it), then they'll need to redo that same work on top of the
reset head of `master`.  This may or may not be a difficult/costly task for
them.

#### Option 2: Revert the revert

I tested this out with a quick test repo. I have to stress that it ***might
work***, I'm not 100% confident that there aren't any cases that I didn't
consider. So be sure to test it out locally with a backup clone of your repo
first. If you choose to use this in your actual repo, please do so at your own
risk.

Also, this may not be the easiest/simplest solution. Its advantage over the
hard-reset option, however, is that it doesn't force developers to have to redo
work on top of a reset `master` branch.

Ok, with all of that out of the way, one thing you could try doing is merging
`master` into `develop`, then revert the revert of the merge from `develop` into
`master`, then merge `develop` into `master` when you're ready. In commands:

```bash
# Coworker accidentally merges develop into master before it's ready
git merge --no-ff develop

# You revert the merge in the master branch (this creates commit "ABCDEFG"
git revert -m 1 <sha of merge commit>

# You want to merge fixes from master into develop
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff master

# But now all that work in develop is reverted, so revert the revert "ABCDEFG"
git revert ABCDEFG

# When you're ready to merge develop into master...
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff develop
```

Here's a sequence of commands I used to test this out in a test repo:

```bash
mkdir practice
cd practice/
git init

touch readme.txt
git add practice.txt
git commit -m "Add practice.txt"

git checkout -b develop

touch feature1.txt
git add feature1.txt
git commit -m "Add feature 1"

touch feature2.txt
git add feature2.txt
git commit -m "Add feature 2"

git checkout master

touch hotfix1.txt
git add hotfix1.txt
git commit -m "Fix issue 1"

git merge --no-ff develop

# Creates commit "ABCDEFG" that reverts the merge
git revert -m 1 head
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff master
git revert ABCDEFG
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff develop
```

You can read more about the "Reverting Revert" technique at the [official Linux
Kernel Git documentation for `git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html#_options):

> `-m parent-number`
>
> `--mainline parent-number`
>
> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side of the
>   merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies the parent
>   number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the
>   change relative to the specified parent.
>
> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes
>   brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree
>   changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously
>   reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.
>
> See the [revert-a-faulty-merge How-To](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) for more details.

The link to [How to revert a faulty merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) is highly recommended if you
fully want to understand how this technique works, it's not difficult to
understand and it actually kind of interesting and fascinating.

Comment: Yep, this is correct, reverting the revert is the way to go. The original revert removes the content but keeps the history; before re-merging from the same branch, you re-introduce the history's content by reverting the revert.

Comment: Thanks! It saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 5):

Something similar was happening with my team. I actually already have a relatively simple solution, I only found this thread because I was researching ways to prevent this from happening in the first place (still no solution for that).

Here's how I fix it, assuming child branch ("develop") was updated (commit M1) prior to "bad" merge (commit M2) with master:

**Problem state**

```
           ... <-- Work after revert that needs merged to develop
            |
            R  <-- Revert Bad Merge
            |
            A  <-- Commits after merge,
            |    /   but before revert 
           ... </    and needs merged to develop
            |
           M2  <-"bad" merge
  ... ____/ |
   | /      |
   M1       |
   | \____  |
  ...     \...
develop   master
```

**Step 1**

```
# Get latest from both parent and child branches locally

git checkout master
git pull
git checkout develop
git pull


# Merge all code from before revert in master branch to develop
# (not necessary if "bad" merge into master was immediately reverted)

git merge A
```

**State after Step 1:**

```
           ... <-- Work after revert that needs merged to develop
   M3       |
   | \____  R  <-- Revert Bad Merge
   |      \ |
   |        A  <-- Commits after merge,
   |        |    /   but before revert
   |       ... </    and needs merged to develop
   |        |
   |       M2  <-"bad" merge
  ... ____/ |
   | /      |
   M1       |
   | \____  |
  ...     \...
develop   master
```

**Step 2 - IMPORTANT PART!**

```
# Use "ours" strategy to merge revert commit to develop.
# This doesn't change any files in develop. 
# It simplly tells git that we've already accounted for that change.

git merge R -s ours
```

**State after Step 2**

```
   M4
   | \____  ... <-- Work after revert that needs merged to develop
   M3     \ |
   | \____  R  <-- Revert Bad Merge
   |      \ |
   |        A  <-- Commits after merge,
   |        |    /   but before revert
   |       ... </    and needs merged to develop
   |        |
   |       M2  <-"bad" merge
  ... ____/ |
   | /      |
   M1       |
   | \____  |
  ...     \...
develop   master
```

**Step 3**

```
# Merge as normal, from the tip of master to develop.
# This should now be an "easy" merge, with only "real" conflicts.
#  (Those that have changed in both branches)
#
# Note: I've had issues using origin master to merge from latest on remote, 
#   so instead I just ensure I've pulled the latest from master locally and 
#   merge from there

git merge master
```

**State after Step 3**

```
   M5
   | \_____
   M4      \
   | \____  ... <-- Work after revert that needs merged to develop
   M3     \ |
   | \____  R  <-- Revert Bad Merge
   |      \ |
   |        A  <-- Commits after merge,
   |        |    /   but before revert
   |       ... </    and needs merged to develop
   |        |
   |       M2  <-"bad" merge
  ... ____/ |
   | /      |
   M1       |
   | \____  |
  ...     \...
develop   master
```

Now `develop` is updated with the latest from `master`, without having had to resolve repetitive or meaningless merge conflicts. Future merges will behave as normal as well.